# cronjob in magento not executing/returning error

Tags: php, mysql, magento, cron

Ok, I got I minor problem with the cronjob.
It would be great if somebody sees it and can help me right away.

Situation:
need to reindex to work around problems during extensive product operations.

Here's my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX>
        <version>x.xxx.xxx</version>
    </XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <models>
        <rebuildindex>
            <class>XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_Model_Index</class>
        </rebuildindex>
    </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <xxxxxxxx_rebuildindex>
            <schedule><cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><modul>rebuildindex/observer::build</modul></run>
        </xxxxxxxx_rebuildindex>
    </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Here's my class:

```
<?php
    class XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_Model_Index_Observer{
    const CHECKTIME = 300;
    public function build(){
        Mage::log('build');
        if(file_exists('pathtofile')){
            $atime = (int)file_get_contents('pathtofile');
            Mage::log($atime);
            if($atime>0 && $atime<(time()-$this->CHECKTIME)){
                @unlink('pathtofile');
                $processCollection = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
                $processCollection->walk('reindexAll');
                Mage::app()->cleanCache();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

It is stored in the path according to models and stuff.
But all I get is:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'No callbacks found' in /pathtomagento/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(99): Mage::throwException('No callbacks fo...')
#1 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /pathtomagento/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#4 /pathtomagento/cron.php(45): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#5 {main}
```

I tried to implement it according to this:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/

but it simply doesn't work

Comment: Not seeing any immediate issues.  I would suggest installing [Aoe_Scheduler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) to get a better idea of how cron is running.

Comment: Hmmmm, I get a note that one executed succcessfully, but I don't see that it was executed :(

Comment: As far as I can see it executes the task, but nothing is written into the main system.log

Comment: Is logging enabled?  Have you tried forced logging? `Mage::log('foo', null 'system.log', true);`

Comment: Loging is enabled. I also get debug Messages from my other debug notes. (If I access the Modul over the frontend)

Comment: I'm calling it now with it's own script and it works quite good. Thx for the help